# yahoo finance and standard library don't want to use pandas

Tags: standards, yahoo, finance

I have checked out pandas and it is AWESOME but I am trying to learn Python and would prefer to code it myself. SO there are many many many ways to get the data from Yahoo (screen scrape, csv and so on) so I am spoiled for choice which is ALSO exciting BUT there has to be an efficient way which has proven to be robust and scalable. I was wondering if anyone knew where I could look to see what others have arrived at.

Up front I need to get each day the last 20 days of closing prices for 100 - 150 stocks so I can run some calculations on them.

I am looking to put together the minimum amount of code to do this that is understandable AND if possible send calculation results to another running python program via an interprocess message. BUT to start with I would like to hear from anyone that had trodden this path before and used the standard libraries as I learn more that way.

I did search these forums but nothing popped up

thanks

Comment: pandas is pretty close to being a standard library, esp. in this domain. You might do better just learning that, as you'll learn enough py doing this anyhow.

Comment: Hey Simon thanks for the excellent guidance. I will of course listen to it BUT I have already coded the HV modules and it was remarkably easy using Python. I'm moving onto implied volatility now so I am in a different realm of fun :-) time to break out the Haug book...